# How to make a gallery of "Videos-Posts" in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, video

In Wordpress, by default, you can create Posts with "**Standard**" or "**Video**" format.

I want to make a Page with a gallery of videos. Where each video is linked to a Post in video format (showing only the videos and its title).

Then the gallery would be updated automatically when I add a new Video-Post, and I could filter/organize the gallery easily by date/category.

For the moment, I am using the plugin Themify builder.
It allows me to make video galleries but I have to specify video URL (youtube etc...), but I want it from a post...
It also allows me to make Post gallery, but the diplay does not correspond to what I want. It shows only the title, or title + contents (but not the video, only the text).

I am wondering if there is a plugin that would allow me to create the kind of gallery I want ?

Comment: You don't need a plugin.  Categorize all of the video posts into the same category, then you can use the "archive" (category listing) for those posts to be all together.  Unless you want all the videos to display on that listing (which is not what you said in your question), in which case you'd need to alter the archive template.

Comment: I need various categories.
I have several pages, Page1 will show a gallery of videos of Category1 and so on...

Comment: Finally I'm going to use the Category page type. That's based on archive template, you were perfectly right. That's what I was looking for. 
Thanks a lot